# How to set constant for a constraint in xib file

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I want to have a constant and use it for leading and trailing constraint in xib files or storyboard.
Then if I change this constant I want all leading and trainings to change

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create outlets of the constraints leading or trailing in class of the xib. Then you should pass the constant values to those constraints.

For example:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Now you pass your constant value whenever you want to change it to these constraints in xib class.

```
leadingConstraint.constant = 80.0(Your constant)
trailingConstraint.constant = 80.0(Your constant)
```

Or if you want to pass it in tableViewDataSource method cellForRowAtIndex:

Then,

```
cell.leadingConstraint.constant = 80.0(Your constant)
cell.trailingConstraint.constant = 80.0(Your constant)
```